# AmCharts Legend, How to reclick an unclicked legend on Data changes in the chart

Tags: angular, typescript, amcharts, amcharts4, legend-properties

I have a [divergent stacked bar chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/divergent-stacked-bars/)  from Am charts that I have built custom filters for, the filters change the data by replacing the entire amChart.data with a new preprepared JSON data.
I'm using Angular 8 with typescript and no backend, the JSON data are saved in the assets and loaded by a service then passed on to the chart.

These are the relevant code snippets, unfortantly I am not alowed to share the entire code.

```
 @Input() dataToDisplay: EventEmitter<any>;

 private amChart: any;

constructor(private wh: WarehouseService) {}

ngOnInit() {
 this.currentYearDisplayed.subscribe(async year => {
  await this.wh.loadData(year);
  this.loadDataIntoChart();
});
this.dataToDisplay.subscribe(data => {
  if (this.amChart) {
    this.amChart.data = data;
    this.amChart.invalidateData();
  }
});
```

}

```
  loadDataIntoChart() {
    if (this.amChart) {
      this.amChart.data = this.wh.filteredSet;
    }
  }
```

[The initial chart looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssOc1.png)

I unclick the Legend Aufwand, the dark blue line disapear.
I click on a filter that changes the data and reloads (while the Aufwand Legend is still uncklicked)

[Chart then looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w1mi.png)

My Legend code is

```
   // Legend
    this.amChart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
    this.amChart.legend.position = "right";
    this.amChart.legend.width = 100;
```

What I have been trying to do, is simply reclick all inactive legends on data change before loading the data, I couldn't find proper setting in the documintation or here in stackoverflow.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unhide hidden series via API by calling `show()` method on its object.

The following will unhide all series:

```
this.amChart.series.each(function(series) {
  series.show();
});
```